# How to strict video file to upload using ValidateRequest in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a user registration form, where i am using file input box to upload image.
Now the problem is , if i will select video file to upload it will pass ValidateRequest .
In ValidateRequest, i already define the rule for image, below is the code:

```
class UserValidateRequest extends Request {

public function __construct() {

}

protected $messages = [
    'required.password' => 'We need to know your e-mail address!',
];
protected $rules = [      
    'first_name' => 'required|regex:"[a-zA-Z 0-9]"',
    'last_name' => 'regex:"[a-zA-Z 0-9]"',
    'image' => ' mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif |max:2048',           
];  

/**
 * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function authorize() {
    return true;
}

public function messages() {
    return [
        'password.regex' => 'Password shall be 8-20 characters, must have a number and an alphabet',           ,
        'image.mimes' => 'Upload Gif || JPG || JPEG || PNG Images Only'
    ];
}

  public function attributes() {
      return[];
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using mime type validation, try to add [image validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-image) to image field:

```
'image' => 'image|max:2048'
```

Comment: I just tried as you said, but know getting this error:
The file "enrique_jordan.mp4" exceeds your upload_max_filesize ini directive (limit is 2048 KiB).
And this error will come with a crash page.
i don't understand why it will pass the image imge validation and crash on size validation

Comment: upload_max_filesize is php.ini directive which limits maximum uploaded file size regardless of its contents. If your file is larger than the specified value, the check will not even be perfomed -- PHP will simply throw the error. Therefore, before validation, you need to make sure that upload_max_filesize set to larger value than size of file which are you trying to upload.